# Are firewalls a bottleneck for persistent http connections?

Tags: firewall, long-polling, http-1.1

I am building a client server application, where clients will use a long-lived http sessions to push data from the server to the client (sometimes referred to as http push, reverse ajax, server push, long-polling, http1.1 etc.)

If I have potentially thousands, or hundreds of thousands of clients all maintaining open connections to the server environment, are there common policies for firewalls/loadbalancers to terminate sessions if they are open for too long? do firewalls/loadbalancers have scalability constraints where they can only host a maximum number of open connections (even if there is no data being sent)?

I am hoping that firewalls and load balancers have features with Http 1.1 to keep sessions open without occupying cpu and memory resources.  If this is not the case, then the firewall is a bottleneck for the number of concurrent open concurrent connections.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're doing things correctly, your HTTP sessions shouldn't be all *that* long.  With most chat implementations using COMET and BOSH (or something similar), the connections aren't held open for longer than a minute or two (after which a new request is made to re-establish the HTTP connection).